# If api server is down, what is the best practice to alerting users that the server is currently unavailable clientside?

Tags: javascript, ajax, error-handling, server

I have a website that basically makes API calls and displays the data in a table; the API is on a different server from the website.
If the API server is down what is the best way to alert the user client-side (JavaScript) that the server is unavailable?

Could/Should I put the alert in the API call error handling (See code for example)? What is the best practice for this type of situation.

```
  function apiCall(query, product){
    var p = product;
    var urlr='https://myFakeAPIUrl/api/'+query+'/'+ product;

    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        crossDomain: true,
        url: urlr,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (result){

            alert("Yay, the API server is up.");    
        },
        error: function(error){ 

            console.log(error);
            alert("Sorry, the server is down.");
        }
    });
}

var productData = apiCall("Produce", "112233");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would ask myself what a user would like to see in this situation.

What I always do is putting a timeout on the Ajax request, whenever that timeout of e.g. 9999ms runs out, the user should get notified (with a toast, a heading, etc..) that something went wrong and that they should try it again later.